# cycles filmic colormanagement to nuke

Tags: color-management, .exr, filmic-blender

I don't seem to be able to bring my filmic EXR to nuke without a shift in brightness or gamma. I'm rendering half (16 bit) and tried to import them in nuke as log. Do I need to customize my projects color settings in nuke? Or do I linearize the filmic log data in blender and import the EXRs linear in nuke? I did my shading without any LUT (basic contrast, ...).

I have tried different input color spaces in the readnode of nuke and I tried to load the filmic *config.ocio* into nukes OCIO settings, both without any success. The resulting image always looks clamped and blown out.

Comment: further reading about filmic: http://blog.thepixelary.com/post/160247878572/filmic-colors-in-blender-and-light-linearity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximeroz has made available filmic config.ocio files for Nuke and also an explanation on how to set it up:-

http://www.maximeroz.com/blog/#/filmic/

http://www.maximeroz.com/filmic-nuke

https://github.com/maximeroz/filmic-blender/tree/dev/extra

It is dated July and November 2017, so I don't know how current the information is.

There is also a config for Maya.

Comment: thank you very much. I found that blogpost, but I couldn't find the git :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include the github link.